# i cant find image gallery slider for next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, slider

i am looking for a slider package for product image gallery and tried many of them.  is there any suggestions to solve my problem?

thank you

1. fullPage.js
2. Swiper
3. React Slick
4. React Responsive Carousel
5. React Flickity
6. React Swipeable
7. Pure React Carousel

Comment: You can use all of this list in your app. You just need to import on your page (product) the slider and configure it.

Comment: I'm using next JS. all of the above packages had style problems or a lack of customization. did you have an experience with the above items?

Comment: No, I prefer to implement my own carousel when working with next.js. Did you already see this: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage

Comment: no. i will check it out. but I developed my own carousel too. tnx